# Remove duplicates records in a MySQL table with key but not primary key

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I need to remove duplicate records (just to keep one copy) from a MySQL table in MyISAM format. I have read many questions in Stackoverflow about similar issues but always the people use an ID field as unique id or similar and I haven't this field because my "Key" could be duplicated. I want to remove rows with the 'Fecha' and 'Equip' duplicated.

```
CREATE TABLE `pfc` (
`Fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
`Equip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`Value` double NOT NULL,
KEY `Fecha` (`Fecha`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=21 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;
```

An example table data:

```
Fecha              | Equip | Value 
06/02/2011 0:00:11 |  22   |  29.0
06/02/2011 0:22:11 |  22   |  45.3
06/02/2011 0:00:11 |  22   |  29.0
```

The result should be:

```
Fecha              | Equip | Value 
06/02/2011 0:00:11 |  22   |  29.0
06/02/2011 0:22:11 |  22   |  45.3
```

This structure is not possible to change. I cannot use PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE INDEX solutions. To create a temporal table without duplicates and then rename would be a poor solutions also, because the KEY and another parameters will be lost.

Thanks

Comment: Why would a temporary table be a poor solution? You can always recreate indexes. Also, if Equip and Fecha are duplicates, what value should be selected if the values differ?

Comment: Temporary tables could be work but not to create a table "new_fc" as "Octopus-Paul" and then rename "new_pfc" to "pfc". How can I use temporaty tables to solve the issue?

Comment: You don't have to use temporary tables, there's more elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: Without temp. table it is not possible. Your table does not have id and MySQL does not support internal row id. The table contains two identical rows - '06/02/2011 0:00:11|22|29.0'. How to specify the line that should be removed?

Comment: @Devart - do you have any source that MySQL doesn't support internal row ids? FYI, it's not up to MySQL but storage engine used.

Comment: @N.B. Of course, storage engine may have internal row id. The question is - how to use it in a SELECT statement?

Comment: @Devart Why would you use it in this case? There's really simple solution how to delete duplicates from poorly designed table without any sort of primary key and without involving temporary tables.

Comment: @N.B. Yes, your solution is simple and good. I was going to use DELETE statement.

Answer (score 9):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `pfc` ADD UNIQUE(`Fetcha`, `Equip`);
```

That will keep the first record it finds and remove duplicates from your table.

From MySQL manual:

> IGNORE is a MySQL extension to standard SQL. It controls how ALTER
>   TABLE works if there are duplicates on unique keys in the new table or
>   if warnings occur when strict mode is enabled. If IGNORE is not
>   specified, the copy is aborted and rolled back if duplicate-key errors
>   occur. If IGNORE is specified, only the first row is used of rows with
>   duplicates on a unique key. The other conflicting rows are deleted.
>   Incorrect values are truncated to the closest matching acceptable
>   value.

Edit:

To create an exact copy of your table, use the following:

`CREATE TABLE table_copy SELECT * FROM pfc;`

That will copy the table structure and the data. After that, run the ALTER command to add the UNIQUE constraint and filter out the records that are duplicated.

Comment: Sorry, as I've said, I cannot use UNIQUE because the format table is untouchable.

Comment: So create a copy of the table, add the constraint, filter the results, truncate the original table and populate it with the contents of the copied table. It's about 2 minutes of work in total. You can TRUNCATE or DELETE FROM, right?

Comment: I _would_ create a copy of the table if the format is _identical_ but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Sorry but the copy is not exact. I get a table like this: `CREATE TABLE `pfc_new` (
  `Fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Equip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Value` double NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: So you're saying that a computer, after being instructed to create an exact copy of the target table, failed to do so and it did something else? Now how can that be? :)

Comment: If I execute your query `CREATE TABLE pfc_new SELECT * FROM pfc;`, I get a table pfc_new with InnoDB engine, without Key field and other things are lost. The original is MyISAM, with Fecha as Key field!

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE pfc;` - copy the result, rename the table name so you can create a copy. After that use `ALTER TABLE table_copy ADD UNIQUE(Fecha, Equip)`. After that, use `INSERT INTO table_copy (Fecha, Equip, Value) SELECT Fecha, Equip, Value FROM pfc ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE;`. Now if that doesn't work, I will concede. Also, never create tables without primary key, it's simply terrible choice (I don't know whether you created the original table or not).

Comment: Sorry but another process can insert new data in the table during this SQL query, so I shouldn't modify the table parameters (to set UNIQUE fields).

Comment: How big is the table in question? If it isn't huge, you can lock it for the duration of changes. On a properly configured MySQL instance (and using InnoDB engine) you can fix the table of such design with 500k rows in under a few seconds. Lock it, do the change, unlock it.

Comment: It uses MyISAM engine because we need high performance to insert data. Moreover, it's not just one table; there are 50 or more and growing. I'm developing a Java application that clean the duplicate rows everyday.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but MyISAM is a poor choice of storage engine - it's got MANY shortcomings. InnoDB has to be tuned in order to get the most out if it and it scales much better as it gets larger (you should notice MyISAM performance degradation around 10m rows). Now as for the 50 tables you mention - are they of the same structure or what? If yes, I'd definitely use InnoDB and partition it using MySQL 's partitioning feature rather than create more and more tables.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a test, try this to see if it is what you want

```
CREATE TABLE new_pfc AS
SELECT * FROM pfc GROUP BY fecha, equip
```

Comment: As I've said, to create a temporal "new_pfc" is a poor solution because the index and another formats are lost. I need to avoid change the table format.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE n1 FROM pfc n1, pfc n2 WHERE n1.Fecha = n2.Fecha AND n1.Equip=n2.Equip AND n1.Value=n2.Value
```